# Generating cpps with Cython and then installing a C extension in one setup.py

Tags: python, cython, distutils, setup.py

I have some `.cpp`s I need to generate from `.pyx`s and `.pxd`s prior to installing a C/C++ extension in my `setup.py` (through a pip local install-- `pip install path/to/my_pkg`). I used to have the `.cpp`s generated separately, but that's gotten really annoying for development and means I constantly have to commit my generated `.cpp`s, which bloat my repo, and I'd rather not do.

I used to just generate my `cpp`s with a `gen_cpp.sh` file like so:

```
cython src/*.pyx src/*.pxd -a --cplus --include-dir ../
```

And then once they were generated, I'd run the setup.py to install everything as a C/C++ extension like so:

```
setup(
    name="MyPKG",
    version="0.1.9",
    description="some description",
    author='me',
    author_email='me@me.com',
    url='http://www.myurl.com'',
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(
            "something",
            sources = glob.glob('src/*.cpp') + glob.glob('lib/b64/*.c'),
            include_dirs=['lib'],
            language = "c++",
        )
    ]
)
```

All I really want to do is just have my `gen_cpp.sh` file run through setup.py to generate the requisite cpps before the rest of the installation is done, but I'm running into a brick wall. I can run `gen_cpp.sh` by subclassing `install` in `setuptools.command.install`:

```
class UpdateAndInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        os.system("sh ./gen_cpp.sh")
        install.run(self)
```

But this runs `gen_cpp.sh` looking for files in the build directory, which obviously doesn't work. I've tried `cd`ing to the current work directory in that script prior to doing anything, but nothing I do gets me to the right place, and this whole approach is feeling hackier and hackier. How do

Comment: What's the reason for not using `cythonize`? http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus I couldn't get it to work with first cythonizing locally and then building the C extension (I'd have both in ext_modules, but only the cython part would be cythonized). I tried this before posting and couldn't get it to work, but maybe I'm missing something.